# Low quality answer of low quality question

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I have been reviewing the low quality posts and found following answer,

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9283745

In this question OP is asking about *bayesian probability*. One user answered this and I don't know what exactly I should do with this post because answer recommended a book. I can have following options,

- Recommend deletion with No Comments
- Just don't consider it low quality and click Looks Good *(I would prefer)*

I am quite confused about it. How to deal with this kind of posts ?

Comment: Does _"Looks Good"_ apply here? Absolutely not. So, recommend deletion (or skip).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does *"Looks Good"* apply here? Absolutely not.

So, recommend deletion or skip this review if you don't feel comfortable with the available options.

Comment: So Recommend deletion with No Comments OR Commentry on another post is the better solution in this case right ?

Comment: Aye, that or a "skip".